# C++ Vector of pointers to files

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I am currently trying to access pointers to files from vector. The problem I am facing and which I can't alone solve is that i am re-writing already stored pointers in vector with the last created (or at least it seems so). 
So if I try access them, only the last is available. 
Maybe there is simple solution to this that I just can't see, but I have spend already three days trying to find what I am doing wrong (I have completely rewritten the code from scratch twice).

```
int cnt = 0;
vector<AbstractInput*> abstractFiles;
while (cnt < 6) {
    string path = "D:/tempSort_" + to_string(cnt) + ".txt";
    ofstream fileOutput(path);
    if (!fileOutput)
    {
        // todo error 
        exit(1);
    }
    AbstractOutput* tmp = new FileOutput(fileOutput, kernel);
    tmp->WriteLine(to_string(cnt) + " zkouska");
    tmp->WriteLine(to_string(cnt) + " zkouska2");
    tmp->WriteLine(to_string(cnt) + " zkouska3");
    tmp->Close();
    delete(tmp);

    ifstream fileInput(path);
    if (!fileInput)
    {
        exit(1);
    }       

    abstractFiles.push_back(&(FileInput(fileInput, kernel)));

    output->WriteLine("CNT = " + to_string(cnt));
    for (AbstractInput* it : abstractFiles)
    {
        bool succes;
        output->WriteLine((it)->ReadLine(succes));
    }       


    cnt++;

}
```

FileInput:

```
using namespace std;

class FileInput : public AbstractInput
{
    using AbstractInput::AbstractInput;


private:
    ifstream& inputFile;
    bool closed;

public:
    FileInput::FileInput(ifstream& inputFile, Kernel* kernel) : 

    AbstractInput(kernel), inputFile{ inputFile }, closed(false)
    {   

    }

    int FileInput::Close()
    {
        inputFile.close();
        closed = true;
        return 0;
    }

    bool FileInput::HasNext()
    {
        return !closed;
    }
    string FileInput::Read()
    {
        return GetKernel()->ReadFromKeyboard();
    }
    string FileInput::ReadLine(bool& success)
    {
        string line = GetKernel()->ReadLineFromFile(inputFile, success);

        closed = !success;
        return line;    
    }

};
```

Kernel functions:

```
string Kernel::ReadLine(istream& stream, bool& success)
{
    string line;
    if (getline(stream, line))
    {
        success = true;
        return line;
    }
    success = false;
    return "";
}

string Kernel::ReadLineFromFile(ifstream& stream, bool& success)
{   
    return ReadLine(stream, success);
}
```

EDIT: Added whole code + FileInput class

EDIT2: Added Kernel functions

EDIT3: I have tried creating new pointers with `&(FileInput(inputFile, kernel))` and with `new FileInput(inputFile, kernel)`. Both ended with same result -> Only last added pointer is valid, others point to same file.

EDIT4: Current output + expected output

Output of current version:

```
CNT = 0
0 zkouska
CNT = 1
1 zkouska
1 zkouska2
CNT = 2
2 zkouska
2 zkouska2
2 zkouska3
CNT = 3
3 zkouska
3 zkouska2
3 zkouska3

CNT = 4
4 zkouska
4 zkouska2
4 zkouska3


CNT = 5
5 zkouska
5 zkouska2
5 zkouska3



.
```

Expect result would be:

```
CNT = 0
0 zkouska
CNT = 1
0 zkouska
1 zkouska
CNT = 2
0 zkouska
1 zkouska
2 zkouska
```

and more... as I am reading only first line from each file so the zkouska1, zkouska2, ... should be never written to output.

Comment: You are taking the address of a temporary that is immediately going to fall out of scope, so your vector has a dangling pointer.

Comment: Additional issue: It seems that at each cycle (of the while loop) you are opening always the same file, as the variable `path` does not change.

Comment: Can you edit your question and append the definition of `FileInput`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the whole code, I will edit it.

Comment: You're still missing some Code. What is `kernel`?

Comment: Done too. Uff new with posting at Stack, until now I was able to find answers to all my questions without need to ask.

Comment: I think `inputFile{ inputFile }` should be `inputFile(_inputFile)`, renaming the parameter variable `inputFile` -> `_inputFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ifstream fileInput(path);
if (!fileInput)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

with

```
std::shared_ptr<ifstream> fileInput(new ifstream(path) );
if (*fileInput)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

And then replace all other instances of `ifstream&` with [`std::shared_ptr<ifstream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (When actually using the stream for reading from file, you will also have to refer to `stream` as `*stream`). That will prevent your file stream object from going out of scope, and will take care of destroying and deallocating your objects when your program ends. (As long as you take care of destroying the objects in your AbstractFiles vector; in fact, you should consider using [`unique_ptr`](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) there).

Regarding your expect output... Well, if you open a file, read one line, and at the next loop you read another line with the same file descriptor, you will necessarily read the subsequent line, unless you reset the stream with something like `fileStream->Seek( 0, SeekOrigin::Begin );` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks too much, at least an solution to my problem :)

Comment: @Chlebnik Where reading my answer would've solved it, too. :)

Comment: @Pixelchemist Well, now you mention it, it's because I have misreaded it :-X. I didn't notice the `auto fileInput = new std::ifstream(path);` part and thought that you are just advising me to use the `new` pointer creation to `FileInput`. My bad, I am sorry.

Comment: @Pixelchemist With the method you propose, with the `fileInput` pointer stored in a local variable, how do you plan to delete the objects you create? Considering OP is a beginner, I think it's important to point him in the direction of smart pointers.

Comment: @Antonio For example by using `delete std::addressof(inputFile);` inside `~FileInput()`.

Comment: @Antonio Where using smart pointers is preferable in the first place, of course. I just commented because of the "at least" comment ;)

Comment: @Pixelchemist I would avoid suggesting (or even mentioning :) ) to use `delete std::addressof(<anything>)` to anybody, especially to a beginner. I understand the origin of your comment.

Comment: @Antonio I terms of giving good advice: I agree. I just pointed out how to get around the issue. This is not code review where I would suggest a mayor overhaul of the whole design anyway. :)

Answer (score 7):

`&(FileInput(fileInput))` is the address of a temporary that holds a reference to a variable.

1. You fill the vector with dangling pointers.
2. Your class contains a reference to a varaible that goes out of scope at the end of the loop.

You want to create non-temporary objects on the heap and store their address.

```
auto fileInput = new std::ifstream(path);
abstractFiles.push_back(new FileInput(*fileInput));
```

Remember to delete those pointers (ifstream and FileInput) properly, afterwards.

*Note: What is the for loop supposed to do? You read one line from each valid entry of `abstractFiles` in each while iteration.*

The output I'd be expecting is:

```
CNT = 0
0 zkouska
CNT = 1
0 zkouska2
1 zkouska
CNT = 2
0 zkouska3
1 zkouska2
2 zkouska
CNT = 3

1 zkouska3
2 zkouska2
3 zkouska
CNT = 4


2 zkouska3
3 zkouska2
4 zkouska
```

Comment: I tryed to to add pointers with `new FileInput(fileInput)` with same failed result before i have even posted this question, meaby I should written that too.

Comment: It would be also important to know what the `FileInput` class does with that `ifstream` object, as also that goes out of scope.

Comment: @Chlebnik So you'll want to add a complete program that shows what happens to `test`, `path` and the definitions of `FileInput`.

Comment: Added rest of code + example of output. Still missing the answer :-/

Comment: @Chlebnik Your `fileInput` is local to the current loop iteration. You cannot store any objects holding a reference to that variable and expect them to be accessible in the next iteration.